# getBytes from NSData and put the result in a string

Tags: swift, cocoa, buffer, nsdata

I'm not able to get some bytes and put them in a string...
I'm using this function to get the data. Everything works well but I can't use a buffer of type string with the function getBytes as it will result in an empty string, even if it the data is not empty.

```
private func getTYPE() {
    let x = NSMutableData(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
    let _mode_: [UInt8] = [0x66, 0x74, 0x79, 0x70]
    let data = NSData(bytes: _mode_, length: _mode_.count)
    let range = x?.range(of: data as Data, in: NSRange(location: 0, length: (x?.length)!))

    // Problems here
    var y: String = ""
    x?.getBytes(&y, range: NSRange(location: (range?.location)! + (range?.length)!, length: 3))
    Swift.print(y) // Print result
}
```

It doesn't throw any kind of exception but the string is always empty...
The same function works well if I try to get just a UInt8 instead of a string:

```
// Working Context
var y: UInt8 = 0
x?.getBytes(&y, range: NSRange(location: (range?.location)! + (range?.length)!, length: 1))
```

So how do I read multiple characters together?

Comment: Data is a MutableCollection of bytes. you can use copyBytes and pass a range.

Comment: `let x = "A test string".data(using: .utf8)!
var y: [UInt8] = [0,0,0]
x.copyBytes(to: &y, from: 0..<3)
y // [65, 32, 116]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is so un-Swift! Presumably you're converting from some old Obj-C code or some such.

As you have figured out, you can pass a pointer to a `UInt8` in to get a byte. If you want several bytes, use an array of `UInt8`s, but if you want a string just use `var s = String(data: ...)`

See the example below (I've removed the range stuff for clarity):

```
let x: NSMutableData = "A test string".data(using: .utf8) as! NSMutableData

var y: [UInt8] = [0,0,0]
x.getBytes(&y, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: 3))
y // [65, 32, 116]

if let s = String(data: x as Data, encoding: .utf8) {
    s // "A test string"
}
```